# Haskell List Generator High Memory Usage

Tags: list, haskell, memory

While working on a competitive programming problem I discovered an interesting issue that drastically reduced the performance of some of my code. After much experimentation I have managed to reduce the issue to the following minimal example:

```
module Main where

main = interact handle

handle :: String -> String
-- handle s = show $ sum l
-- handle s = show $ length l
-- handle s = show $ seq (length l) (sum l)
  where
    l = [0..10^8] :: [Int]
```

If you uncomment each commented line individually, compile with `ghc -O2 test.hs` and run with `time ./test > /dev/null`, you should get something like the following:

For `sum l`:

```
0.02user 0.00system 0:00.03elapsed 93%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3380maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+165minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

For `length l`:

```
0.02user 0.00system 0:00.02elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3256maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+161minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

For `seq (length l) (sum l)`:

```
5.47user 1.15system 0:06.63elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 7949048maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1986697minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Look at that huge increase in peak memory usage. This makes some amount of sense, because of course both sum and length can lazily consume the list as a stream, while the `seq` will be triggering the evaluation of the whole list, which must then be stored. But the `seq` version of the code is using just shy of 8 GB of memory to handle a list that contains just 400 MB of actual data. The purely functional nature of Haskell lists could explain some small constant factor, but a 20 fold increase in memory seems unintended.

This behaviour can be triggered by a number of things. Perhaps the easiest way is using `force` from `Control.DeepSeq`, but the way in which I originally encountered this was while using `Data.Array.IArray` (I can only use the standard library) and trying to construct an array from a list. The implementation of `Array` is monadic, and so was forcing the evaluation of the list from which it was being constructed.

If anyone has any insight into the underlying cause of this behaviour, I would be very interested to learn why this happens. I would of course also appreciate any suggestions as to how to avoid this issue, bearing in mind that I have to use just the standard library in this case, and that every `Array` constructor takes and eventually forces a list.

I hope you find this issue as interesting as I did, but hopefully less baffling.

**EDIT:** user2407038's comment made me realize I had forgotten to post profiling results. I have tried profiling this code and the profiler simply states that 100% of allocations are performed in `handle.l`, so it seems that simply anything that forces the evaluation of the list uses huge amounts of memory. As I mentioned above, using the `force` function from `Control.DeepSeq`, constructing an `Array`, or anything else that forces the list causes this behaviour. I am confused as to why it would ever require 8 GB of memory to compute a list containing 400 MB of data. Even if every element in the list required two 64-bit pointers, that is still only a factor of 5, and I would think GHC would be able to do something more efficient than that. If not this is an obvious bottleneck for the `Array` package, as constructing any array inherently requires us to allocate far more memory than the array itself.

So, ultimately: Does anyone have any idea why forcing a list requires such huge amounts of memory, which has such a high cost on performance?

**EDIT:** user2407038 provided a link to the very helpful [GHC Memory Footprint](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Memory_Footprint) reference. This explains exactly the data sizes of everything, and almost entirely explains the huge overhead: An `[Int]` is specified as requiring 5N+1 words of memory, which at 8 bytes per word gives 40 bytes per element. In this example that would suggest 4 GB, which accounts for half the total peak usage. It is easy to then believe that the evaluation of sum would then add a similar factor, so this answers my question.

Thanks to all commenters for your help.

**EDIT:** As I mentioned above, I originally encountered this behaviour why trying to construct an `Array`. Having had a bit of a dig into [`GHC.Arr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.0.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Arr.html#unsafeArray') I have found what I think is the root cause of this behaviour when constructing an array: The constructor folds over the list to compose a program in the ST monad that it then runs. Obviously the ST can't be executed until it is completely composed, and in this case the ST construct will be large and linear in the size of the input. To avoid this behaviour we would have to somehow modify the constructor to stream elements from the list as it adds them in ST.

Comment: You've already identified the underlying cause of this behaviour: "both sum and length can lazily consume the list as a stream, while the seq will be triggering the evaluation of the whole list, which must then be stored". If you want to know what exactly is the source of the allocation, you should profile the program with GHCs profiler, not `time`, which is obviously fairly rudimentary. It is impossible to say how to avoid it without seeing the actual program; in this simple case, it is obviously to use `sum l` instead of `seq (length l) (sum l)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention I had already done this. I will edit the post to be more clear, but profiling reveals that 100% of allocations are performed when computing `handle.l`. The issue here is I can't see what it could possibly be doing to require just shy of 8 GB of working memory to compute a 400 MB list.

Comment: My back-of-the envelope estimate looks like this: You have 1e8 elements / list nodes. Every list node consists of a pointer to type information (8 bytes), a constructor tag (probably 8 bytes too because of alignment), and a pointer to the actual `Int` value (8 bytes). Every `Int` consists of a pointer to type information (8 bytes) and the numeric value (8 bytes). That's `1e8 * (8 * 5) / 1e9 = 1.3` gigabytes of data right there, without taking lazy evaluation into account.

Comment: You would expect simply manifesting the list to take at least `4*400MB` of space (see [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Memory_Footprint)); but you are not simply manifesting it. This is seemingly the source of your misunderstanding; a list representing 400MB of data simply will not take 400MB of space. If you genuinely need to stream data of this size, you will almost certainly need to use a streaming abstraction to get the performance you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry if I am being unclear. I am aware of the overhead, just I would expect the overhead to be a smaller factor than 20. The memory footprint page you linked is very helpful, and I will keep it on hand for the future, and very nearly answers my question: It specifies that an `[Int]` is 5 N + 1 _words_. At 8 bytes per word on 64-bit arch, that gives 40 bytes per element, so we would expect my list of 10^8 to be 4 GB. This is still only half of what I am seeing in practise, but is close enough to satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple factors that come to play here. The first one is that GHC will lazily lift `l` out of `handle`. This would enable `handle` to reuse `l`, so that you don't have to recalculate it every time, but in this case it creates a space leak. You can check this if you `-ddump-simpl`ified core:

```
Main.handle_l :: [Int]                                                   
[GblId,                                                                  
 Str=DmdType,                                                            
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Value=False, ConLike=False,         
         WorkFree=False, Expandable=False, Guidance=IF_ARGS [] 40 0}]    
Main.handle_l =                                                          
  case Main.handle3 of _ [Occ=Dead] { GHC.Types.I# y_a1HY ->             
  GHC.Enum.eftInt 0 y_a1HY                                               
  }
```

The functionality to calculate the `[0..10^7]` <sup><sub>1</sub></sup> is hidden away in other functions, but essentially, `handle_l = [0..10^7]`, at top-level (`TopLvl=True`). It won't get reclaimed, since you may or may not use `handle` again. If we use `handle s = show $ length l`, `l` itself will be inlined. You will not find any `TopLvl=True` function that has type `[Int]`.

So GHC detects that you use `l` twice and creates a top-level CAF. How big is that CAF? An `Int` takes two words:

```
data Int = I# Int#
```

One for `I#`, one for `Int#`. How much for `[Int]`?

```
data [a] = [] | (:) a ([a]) -- pseudo, but similar
```

That's one word for `[]`, and three words for `(:) a ([a])`. A list of `[Int]` with size N will therefore have a total size of (3N + 1) + 2N words, in your case 5N+1 words. Given your memory, I assume a word is 8byte on your plattform, so we end up with

```
5 * 10^8 * 8 bytes = 4 000 000 000 bytes
```

So how do we get rid of that list? The first option we have is to get rid of `l`:

```
handle _ = show $ seq (length [0..10^8]) (sum [0..10^8])
```

This will now run in constant memory due to `foldr/buildr` rules. While we have `[0..10^8]` there twice, they don't share the same name. If we check the `-s`tats, we will see that it runs in constant memory:

```
> SO.exe +RTS -s                                                                
5000000050000000   4,800,066,848 bytes allocated in the heap                    
         159,312 bytes copied during GC                                         
          43,832 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))                          
          20,576 bytes maximum slop                                             
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)        

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause   
  Gen  0      9154 colls,     0 par    0.031s   0.013s     0.0000s    0.0000s   
  Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0002s   

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)                                    
  MUT     time    4.188s  (  4.232s elapsed)                                    
  GC      time    0.031s  (  0.013s elapsed)                                    
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)                                    
  Total   time    4.219s  (  4.247s elapsed)                                    

  %GC     time       0.7%  (0.3% elapsed)                                       

  Alloc rate    1,146,284,620 bytes per MUT second                              

  Productivity  99.3% of total user, 98.6% of total elapsed
```

But that's not really nice, since we now have to track all the uses of `[0..10^8]`. What if we create a function instead?

```
handle :: String -> String
handle _ = show $ seq (length $ l ()) (sum $ l ())
  where
    {-# INLINE l #-}
    l _ = [0..10^7] :: [Int]
```

This works, but we **must** inline `l`, otherwise we get the same problem as before if we use opti­miza­tions. `-O1` (and `-O2`) enable `-ffull-laziness`, which—together with common sub­expres­sion eli­mi­na­tion—would lift `l ()` to the top. So we either need to inline it or use `-O2 -fno-full-laziness` to prevent that behaviour.

---

<sup><sub>1</sub></sup> Had to decrease the list size, otherwise I would have started swapping.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I think this information will be valuable to anyone who encounters this behaviour (a large part of the reason I made this post), so I am going to mark it as the answer. You may be interested in seeing my most recent edit, where I like to the code that triggers this behaviour in my case.